# Selecting multi database in Navicat

Tags: mysql, postgresql, navicat

I'm having a trouble on how can I `Select` multidatabase in Navicat version 15. I tried using `Union` but it seems it doesn't recognize the other database based on the error on the image below. The thing is my first database is using localhost mysql the other one is postgres connection it is possible to join this in selecting queries?

*Screenshot:*
[image]

```
SELECT T1.covid_id FROM payroll.`app_person` T1
UNION
SELECT T2.id
FROM matchy_data.`b2_benes_accounting` T2
```

Comment: It seems to be possible when you have `Navicat Premium`, see: https://www.navicat.com/en/company/aboutus/blog/1059-how-to-query-across-multiple-databases

Comment: @Luuk Yes i've been following this documentation but the problem is it seems it didn't recognize the other table

Comment: I just installed the evaluation version, but i do not see how to accomplish this. I do not have plans on purchasing the Premium version,..... Maybe you have to get into contact with their support department?

Comment: This works fine even with the free version. There are no restrictions on the queries you write. So the only answer is: the table does not exists...

Comment: @Claus Bönnhoff Thanks for your response. I've been wondering if there's any restriction in terms of database sql table the error describes does not exist is postgres database.

Comment: You cannot select from two complete different databases in one query

Comment: @Claus Bönnhoff Yes I didn't work if there are two different server but is there anyway how to connect those databases?

Comment: No not with one query. Then you need to db connections and two queries